# Reading a JSON file and trying to find a specific value in it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Discord slash command that works like a Dokkan simulator, the user creates their own passive and they can generate some stats based on their input.

My main issue is trying to read the JSON file where I store all the passives and I want to search for the "PassiveName" and see if it matches what the user entered.

Once it's confirmed that a correct match has been found I will then execute my function where I generate the Stats

So far this is what I have when im trying to read the JSON file, my approach is that i read the JSON and store all its members in a list and then search the list for the correct passive name that the user entered

```
        private void ReadJSONFile(string nameSearch) 
        {
            List<object> Passives = new List<object>(); //List to temporarily store everything from the JSON
            try 
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("UserPassivesStorage.json"))
                {
                    string jsonFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    JSONObject100 jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONObject100>(jsonFile);

                    Passives.Add(jsonObject);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.members.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < jsonObject.members.Length)
                        {
                            var data = jsonObject.members[i];
                            Passives.Add(data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

This current code reads the JSON and successfully puts it into the list, but I can't even read from the list to compare the user input to whatever is in storage

This is my JSON file, I have 2 entries in it as an example

```
{
  "userPassiveStorage": "Storage for user created passives using /passivecreator",
  "members": [
    {
      "UserName": ".",
      "PassiveName": "TEQ Gogeta",
      "UnitHP": 19199,
      "UnitATK": 20744,
      "UnitDEF": 10909,
      "UnitLeaderName": "Fusion",
      "UnitLeaderSkill": 170,
      "UnitPassiveATK": 200,
      "UnitPassiveDEF": 200,
      "Support": 0,
      "Links": "No Links Provided by the user"
    },
    {
      "UserName": ".",
      "PassiveName": "AGL Gogeta",
      "UnitHP": 15745,
      "UnitATK": 16492,
      "UnitDEF": 11088,
      "UnitLeaderName": "Movie Heroes",
      "UnitLeaderSkill": 170,
      "UnitPassiveATK": 100,
      "UnitPassiveDEF": 100,
      "Support": 0,
      "Links": "No Links Provided by the user"
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I want to figure out is how can i read this JSON file and search it for the "PassiveName" property so I can access what is stored in it and if it's correct, I load the whole member in to do the stat calculations later on. (For example user enters "TEQ Gogeta", i want it to match to the TEQ gogeta in the JSON)

Comment: What does this mean: _"but I can't even read from the list to compare the user input to whatever is in storage"_???

Comment: What I meant is that when the user enters what they wanna search for, i tried to compare it to whatever was in the list and see if there is a match and if so, load that specific member and its details so if someone searches for "TEQ Gogeta" i want it to load the entire member that has the "PassiveName" : "TEQ Gogeta"

Comment: OK. So what's preventing you from loading up the entire member if you find a match?

Comment: Please check your code, You're not searching anything as you didn't use the `nameSearch` parameter. Also on your `Passives` list, you already added the whole json file, then on the loop you are also adding each object on the list as well.

Comment: indeed, as Henry said, you didn't really introdice any condition checks, only iteration through an array, still, as in the answer below you can skip most of the logic and simply specify 'declaratively' what you expect to get, using LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using LINQ to avoid all the trouble with `for` loops and checking array lengths,etc. To find all members, whose PassiveName matches the search name you can use `Where` method:

```
var matchingMembers = jsonObject.members.Where(member => member.PassiveName == nameSearch);
```

and LINQ does the job returning an IEnumerable. If you want a list out of it:

```
var membersList = matchingMembers.ToList();
```

You can replace `member.PassiveName == nameSearch` condition to anything like `StartsWith` or `Contains` or add further processing.

Of course your JSONObject100 class must have all the needed properties to map to the Json object.

Note, the above requires importing Linq namespace. See docs for more details. You should also add null checks to cover cases where json is missing some parts.

EDIT: If for some reasons you'd prefer to stick to your original approach, what you're missing is mostly the comparison of the pattern with the values youre iterating:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.members.Length; i++)
 {
       var member = jsonObject.members[i];
       if(member.PassiveName == nameSearch)
           return member;
 }
```

You don't need to check condition `i < jsonObject.members.Length` again as for loop does it for you. Even better than for would be foreach here:

```
foreach(var member in jsonObject.members) {...}
```

If you can have more than 1 result, you should add them to a list and then return a list, or print, or whatever is the purpose.

Comment: would be nice if those negging the answer would at least provide a comment about why they don't think it's applicable

Comment: Yep thank you so much, I may have sounded very dumb when asking that question but no matter where I looked there wasn't a clear solution to what I was looking for so yeah I managed to implement the LINQ way of searching my JSON file and it does work correctly. Thank you

Comment: great, if the answer helped you make sure to mark it as selected :)